# zip compression with C++ on ARM board

Tags: c++, zip, compression, mbed

I've downloaded and tested some zip libraries out there like zlib, miniz and minilzo. When I put it in the Keil software to build it and load it on the ARM board, it can't be builded because a lot of error like it can't find that header file etc.
It seems like it's all about OS and depends on the OS, and on Windows it runs well, while for the ARM board it doesn't.
I'm using Mbed board model STM32F746.
Any ideas? I would like to get some help. tnx

Comment: LZMA should work fine on small boards.

Comment: thanks for it! 
(1) I searched and find out that XZ utils is the new version of LZMA. In this link ( http://tukaani.org/xz/ ) i see the section of "Supported platforms". but I don't have any OS platform on my Mbed board model STM32F746.
(2) Which files are the ones who I need to put them in the header directory?
 I would love to get help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a compression library that does not depend on any file system APIs, as they will not be available on embedded. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767640/compact-decompression-library-for-embedded-use) is a list of libraries that would potentially work.